# How to use preg_match with file_get_contents using PHP?

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

How to use the preg_match correctly with file_get_content? I have a form that user can login, if the user input a wrong info, the default echo inside file_get_contents will be replace with a new message using preg_match but it's not working.

I have a PHP snippet but I just get only a white blank page.

```
$reply = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if(preg_match($reply, 'No information was found'){
    echo("<script>location.href = '/page/message/';</script>");
} else {
    echo $reply;   
    echo '<div>
   For any other questions please contact us Monday - Sunday 9am - 6pm at <strong style="color: #000;">1235456</strong> or <strong style="color: #000;">info@example.com</strong>
    </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pattern you have to use a delimiter use

$reply = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

```
if(preg_match('/No information was found/', $reply)){
    echo("<script>location.href = '/page/message/';</script>");
} else {
    echo $reply;   
    echo '<div>
   For any other questions please contact us Monday - Sunday 9am - 6pm at <strong style="color: #000;">1235456</strong> or <strong style="color: #000;">info@example.com</strong>
    </div>';
}
```

Add a `/` delimiter also `preg_match` first parameter is pattern you are using pattern in second parameter